# SQL Server Alwayson and replication merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can replication Merge be done in a highly available environment?
I tried to create the publisher in a partially contained database and it generates the error 21147 of sql,

Can the Express version of the SQL server be within a high availability group in the secondary nodes?

not have my database partially contained within a group of high availability that has consequences?

I hope you can help me with this topic, I thank you in advance for any contribution.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.